# springfox-swagger : model with SnakeCaseStrategy support

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm currently using Springfox Swagger to document my spring boot application with a Java config. 
When I add
    *@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)*
on my model class, and execute the application from swagger ui, its giving me null pointer exception.

But code runs if you try to run from postman or some java client.

I want all my model attributes in snake case. Looks like swagger is not able to serialize/deserialize the object. Please let me know if there is any workaround